# Add Class to WooCommerce Add to Cart Button (only if it is not "Select Option" button)

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to add a class to the WooCommerce Add to cart button.

I'm able to make changes to the Add to cart button via `woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php`

**Here is what I changed my add-to-cart.php file to**

```
/**
 * Loop Add to Cart
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
  * @version     2.1.0
  */

 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
     exit; // Exit if accessed directly
 }

 global $product;

 echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
     sprintf( '<div class="add-to-cart-container"><a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s product_type_%s single_add_to_cart_button button alt ajax_add_to_cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp; %s</a></div>',
         esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
         esc_attr( $product->id ),
         esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
         esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
         $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
         esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
         esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
     ),
 $product );
```

I only want the `ajax_add_to_cart` class in the `<a>` applied to simple products, not the variable products that have a button with "Select options" text. but I'd like all other changes to be applied to both buttons.

How can this be done?

Comment: How can I tell a product is simple or variable? Some specific attribute?

Comment: I inspected the Add to cart button (both "Add to cart" and "Select options"). I do know that a variable product ("Select options" button) has a class `product_type_variable` and a simple product ("Add to cart" button) has a class `product_type_simple`

A work around I did for this was remove the `ajax_add_to_cart` class form the `add-to-cart.php` file and use jQuery to add the class to the correct button

$('.products .product_type_simple').addClass("ajax_add_to_cart");

Comment: Well, if you do have access to the PHP code I'd suggest you do as I suggested in my answer. I think this is cleaner because you would leave the whole logic in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `ajax_add_to_cart` for `%s` and add one more parameter to your `sprintf` function.

```
sprintf( '<div class="add-to-cart-container"><a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s product_type_%s single_add_to_cart_button button alt %s"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp; %s</a></div>',
     esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
     esc_attr( $product->id ),
     esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
     esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
     $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
     esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
     $product->product_type == 'simple' ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
     esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
 ),
```

Comment: `// Assuming $product->type as the type property`
`$product->product_type == 'simple' ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',`

Is doing the trick!

Comment: I actually changed that to a condition that checks the product class, since you had said that this is the correct way to know whether it's simple or variable :)

Comment: Your first answer before edit worked. as long as it's `$product->product_type` not `$product->type`

Comment: Great, I'll change it back

Comment: Thanks a lot. Greatly appreciated!